# An easy solution in R? Binding several numbered data frames

Tags: r, gis, spatial, points

I have 408 "Spatial Points" Data Frames, each numbered as follows:

Points1, Points2,..., Points408.

What I want is to loop through all of them, adding them to a list. I would then like to row bind them to create one huge Spatial Points file.

When I type "Points1" into R, this is printed:

```
              x         y
  [1,] 40.38285 -11.54500
  [2,] 38.41897 -13.55959
  [3,] 38.51536 -12.42431
  [4,] 38.82389 -12.95476
  [5,] 39.88932 -12.77925
  [6,] 39.86099 -13.32380
  [7,] 38.47942 -14.10968
  [8,] 39.85796 -11.84176
  [9,] 38.16891 -13.70572
 [10,] 39.89386 -12.21040
 [11,] 38.32758 -14.03576
 [12,] 39.97627 -11.97127
 [13,] 38.50884 -14.07678
 [14,] 39.06521 -12.19818
 [15,] 39.40532 -13.68988
```

Please note that each Points data frame has the same number of points.

What I want is one huge file that has 15*408=6120 Spatial Points.

Thanks so much!

Comment: May be you can place them in a list and rbind it all. `lst <- mget(paste0('Points",1:408)); do.call(rbind, lst)` It might be helpful to show the `dput` of the example you posted

Comment: BTW, your output looks more like a matrix than a data.frame.

Comment: Hi akrun, that actually is a really good idea, thank you so much! ping, when I write summary(Points1), I get: Object of class SpatialPoints.

Comment: @Cornelius Have you tried the code?  I couldn't test it as the spatial points dataframe structure would be different than the usual dataframe

Comment: Instead of do.call(rbind, lst), you can use rbindlist(lst) provided by data.table. It'll be more efficient.